# What is the best practice for useAxios hook with Redux's slice?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, axios, redux-toolkit

I've created a useAxios hook to use for Axios calls and also reduxjs/toolkit for handling React data. Is it the correct practice to use them together?

For example, in slice.js

```
export const getTodo = (data) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(`${URL}/${data}`);
    dispatch(getTodo(response.data));
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error(err);
  }
};
```

When I replace `` await axios.get(`${URL}/${data}`); `` to `useAxios()`hook, I got the error: hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.

What is the **best practice** for Redux to use the Axios hook? or it's not possible? Any good example? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**The *only* place you can *ever* call a React hook is inside of a function component, or another hook*.  You can *never* call a hook anywhere else.